I'm looking for the name of a martial arts movie
I will be as specific as I can, but I highly doubt anyone will know the name of the movie I'm looking for. It is an old Martial arts movie, likely Kung Fu, so Chinese. I seen it as a kid in the late 80's, so obviously it would pre-date that. What I remember from the film is the signature move of the Hero; he would knock an enemy to the ground then jump high into the air and come down like a dive, as you would into water, with his hands out, palms forward, and land on the chest of the enemy, crushing his chest, a fatal move. I vaguely remember him not being able to use it for a while, because he had a bad experience with it once, but as you do he had to overcome that in order to defeat the evil bad guy in the movie. Anyway, I'm sure even the most seasoned of Martial Arts movie addicts will have trouble figuring out what I am talking about, but here's hoping, it was one that has stuck in my memory, unfortunately the name of it didn't.

You've really got to work on your opening lines :P

Ha, yeah, it's more pessimistic than condescending :)

It was pretty grainy but was in colour, if I guess I'd say it's 80's but it could be late 70's. With the success of Bruce Lee, they were making a dozen for a dime at the time so my doubt comes from the sheer number of similar movies that were pumped out at that time.

If you're still looking, might it be Kung Fu Hustle (2004)? It features a move called the Buddha Palm which involved jumping straight up (to a ridiculous height) and diving down hands first. 
Sing (the Hero) previously tried to use the techniques (though not the finishing move) in his childhood to defend a girl after teaching himself out of a manual but failed and got beat up and peed on.

Asked to explain his escape skills, Sing describes his childhood: he
  bought a Buddhist Palm manual from a beggar and trained himself to be
  a martial artist, but when he tried to defend a mute girl from
  bullies, he was beaten up and humiliated.  

Video of Sing's childhood humiliation: 



As an adult he finally mastered the technique and used it to epically defeat the same (now adult) bully that beat him up as a child.

At Pig Sty Alley, Sing undergoes a metamorphosis; the Beast's
  thrashing has inexplicably awoken his true potential as a kung-fu
  genius. He quickly recovers from his wounds, and suggests that the
  Landlord and Landlady rest. He easily defeats the Axe Gang before
  confronting the Beast. The two engage in a fierce brawl before the
  Beast uses his Toad Style techniques to send Sing rocketing into the
  sky. As he falls back to earth, Sing comes to terms with the Buddha
  and the techniques he learned from the manual as a child, and delivers
  the Buddhist Palm to defeat the Beast.

Video of the epic version of the Buddha Palm in action: 




Any chance it might be Snake in the Eagle's Shadow? it's an early Jackie Chan and he develops his own cat style (complete with cat shrieks), which sounds like what you describe, but his hesitations were not due to bad experience with this move, rather his horrid uncle. If it's not, it's a movie worth watching if you haven't already - for the comedy value alone!

"for the comedy value alone!" - And for the great synthesizer soundtrack!

Agreed, I very nearly forgot about that!

Thanks but no, that's not it. I watched the final fight and yes, I see the appeal. I'm pretty sure it isn't a well known martial arts actor in the movie I'm looking for. For some reason I have a feeling it was Ho Chung Tao, aka Bruce Li, named for his resemblance to Lee, but I'm not certain.
